# Web Service to expose a generic database

Tags: database, web-services

I'm looking for a web service that can be installed on a machine and access a generic database (SQL Server and MySQL being the alternatives at the moment), exposing CRUD functionalities.

I should be able to write it myself, but I prefer an industrial grade solution.

any advice?

thank you in advance

stefano

Answer (score 0):

I would use a factory like this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DBaseFactGenerics.aspx

You can connect to any database for which .Net has a provider.